# adding page numbers when programatically merging PDFs with acrobat

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation, acrobat

Hi the code below merges pdfs using adobe acrobat. It works but I am looking to add page numbers to the document so that if I merge 2 documents that are 4 pages each the page numbers go from 1 to 8.  How can that be done?

Here is the code:

```
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47310-Need-code-to-merge-PDF-files-in-a-folder-using-adobe-acrobat-X
Sub MergePDFs()
     ' ZVI:2013-08-27 http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47310-Need-code-to-merge-PDF-files-in-a-folder-using-adobe-acrobat-X
     ' Reference required: "VBE - Tools - References - Acrobat"

     ' --> Settings, change to suit
    Const MyPath = "C:\mypath" '"C:\Temp" ' Path where PDF files are stored
    Const MyFiles = "file1.pdf,file2.pdf" ' List of PDFs to ne merged
    Const DestFile = "MergedFile.pdf" ' The name of the merged file
     ' <-- End of settings

    Dim a As Variant, i As Long, n As Long, ni As Long, p As String
    Dim AcroApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp, PartDocs() As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

    If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then p = MyPath Else p = MyPath & "\"
    a = Split(MyFiles, ",")
    ReDim PartDocs(0 To UBound(a))

    On Error GoTo exit_
    If Len(Dir(p & DestFile)) Then Kill p & DestFile
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
         ' Check PDF file presence
        If Dir(p & Trim(a(i))) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File not found" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
            Exit For
        End If
         ' Open PDF document
        Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        PartDocs(i).Open p & Trim(a(i))

        If i Then
             ' Merge PDF to PartDocs(0) document
            ni = PartDocs(i).GetNumPages()
            If Not PartDocs(0).InsertPages(n - 1, PartDocs(i), 0, ni, True) Then
                MsgBox "Cannot insert pages of" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
            End If
             ' Calc the number of pages in the merged document
            n = n + ni
             ' Release the memory
            PartDocs(i).Close
            Set PartDocs(i) = Nothing
        Else
             ' Calc the number of pages in PartDocs(0) document
            n = PartDocs(0).GetNumPages()
        End If
    Next

    If i > UBound(a) Then
         ' Save the merged document to DestFile
        If Not PartDocs(0).Save(PDSaveFull, p & DestFile) Then
            MsgBox "Cannot save the resulting document" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        End If
    End If

exit_:

     ' Inform about error/success
    If Err Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error #" & Err.Number
    ElseIf i > UBound(a) Then
        MsgBox "The resulting file is created:" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbInformation, "Done"
    End If

     ' Release the memory
    If Not PartDocs(0) Is Nothing Then PartDocs(0).Close
    Set PartDocs(0) = Nothing

     ' Quit Acrobat application
    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

attached a stand-alone VBS/VBA script, which add the page number as footer to your pdf. You may took out the parts you need and write into your script just before you save the pdf or execute it afterwards.

Full Script:

```
File = "D:\Test.pdf"

Set App = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")      '//start acrobat
app.show                                    '//show Acrobat or comment out for hidden mode
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")   '//get AFormAPI to execute js later

If AVDoc.Open(File,"") Then
    '//write JS-Code on a variable
    Ex = "  //  set Date, filename and PageNo as footer "&vbLF _
      & "  var Box2Width = 50  "&vbLF _
      & "  for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)   "&vbLF _
      & "   {   "&vbLF _
      & "    var aRect = this.getPageBox(""Crop"",p);  "&vbLF _
      & "    var TotWidth = aRect[2] - aRect[0]  "&vbLF _
      & "     {  var bStart=(TotWidth/2)-(Box2Width/2)  "&vbLF _
      & "         var bEnd=((TotWidth/2)+(Box2Width/2))  "&vbLF _
      & "         var fp = this.addField(String(""xftPage""+p+1), ""text"", p, [bStart,30,bEnd,15]);   "&vbLF _
      & "         fp.value = ""Page: "" + String(p+1)+ ""/"" + this.numPages;  "&vbLF _
      & "         fp.textSize=6;  fp.readonly = true;  "&vbLF _
      & "         fp.alignment=""center"";  "&vbLF _
      & "     }  "&vbLF _
      & "   }  "
    '//Execute JS-Code
       AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript Ex
    msgBox("Done")
end if

Set AVDoc = Nothing
Set APP = Nothing
```

The parts you really need if you only want to take over in your script:

```
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")  
Ex = "  //  set Date, filename and PageNo as footer "&vbLF _
  & " .....

  & " .....
  & "   }  "
'//Execute JS-Code
 AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript Ex
```

This also demonstrates how you can use/execute AcroJs via VBS/VBA without translating to JSO (Java Script Object).

Good luck, Reinhard